# SQL - Subquery/JOINS/Having - wrong record

Tags: sql, join, subquery, having

I have a problem with one SQL exercise:
In which places, examiner with the surname 'Muryjas' examined more than 2 students?
We have 3 tables:
- Places (Id_place, Place_name)
- Exams (Id_examiner,Id_student, Id_place)
- Examiners (Id_examiner, Examiner_name)

```
SELECT p.Place_name
FROM Places p
INNER JOIN Egzams e ON e.Id_place = p.Id_place
INNER JOIN Egzaminers ee ON ee.Id_egzaminer = e.Id_egzaminer
WHERE ee.name = "Muryjas" 
GROUP BY p.Nazwa_o
HAVING COUNT(e.Id_student) > 2
```

Expected result : should print 2 records 
Actual result: I have 3 records, one is wrong.

Should I use subquery? But I don't have any idea how to implement this feature. Any suggestions?

Comment: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.Id_student)

Comment: Ouch. This is good answer. Totally don't know why i didn't check student ids :)

Answer (score 0):

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.Id_student)